# Sort a List using a comparator with multiple criteria. FIFO

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

I have a problem with sorting the list, I did all of the tasks which are in a given exercise, but it doesn't quite make sense to me and I want to fix it. So I have a List of people who are waiting in the queue in, let's say, a pharmacy. People who are pregnant should have priority above everyone, the next priority has people with age >60. Everything works fine, except the fact the person with age >60 which came first is behind the people with age >60 who came later (I just need it to work with a FIFO rule, with the pregnant criteria it works as expected).

I sorted the list first with the `compareTo()` method and then with the external comparator class I created.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Customer> pharmacyQueue = new ArrayList<>();
        CustomerComparator customerComparator = new CustomerComparator();

        pharmacyQueue.add(new Customer(25, false, "Przemek"));
        pharmacyQueue.add(new Customer(35, true, "Anita"));
        pharmacyQueue.add(new Customer(55, false, "Wiesława"));
        pharmacyQueue.add(new Customer(25, true, "Maryja"));
        pharmacyQueue.add(new Customer(85, false, "Halinka"));
        pharmacyQueue.add(new Customer(55, false, "Stasia"));
        pharmacyQueue.add(new Customer(20, true, "Marta"));
        pharmacyQueue.add(new Customer(65, false, "Bożenka"));
        pharmacyQueue.add(new Customer(75, false, "Paoasdo"));

        Collections.sort(pharmacyQueue); 
        Collections.sort(pharmacyQueue, customerComparator);

        System.out.println("Sorted queue: ");
        for (Customer c : pharmacyQueue){
            System.out.println(c);
        }

    }
}
```

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public class Customer implements Comparable<Customer> {
    private int age;
    private boolean isPregnant;
    private String name;

    public int compareTo(Customer o) {
        if (this.age > 60){
            return -1;
        }else if (this.age < 60){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

```java
public class CustomerComparator implements Comparator<Customer> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Customer o1, Customer o2) {


        if (o1.isPregnant() && !o2.isPregnant()){
            return -1;
        }
        if (o1.isPregnant() && o2.isPregnant()){
            return 1;
        }


        return 0;
    }
}
```

The result:

```
Sorted queue: 
Customer(age=35, isPregnant=true, name=Anita) //fine
Customer(age=25, isPregnant=true, name=Maryja) //fine
Customer(age=20, isPregnant=true, name=Marta) //fine
Customer(age=75, isPregnant=false, name=Paoasdo) //should be 6th
Customer(age=65, isPregnant=false, name=Bożenka) //should be 5th
Customer(age=85, isPregnant=false, name=Halinka) //should be 4th
Customer(age=25, isPregnant=false, name=Przemek) //fine
Customer(age=55, isPregnant=false, name=Wiesława) //fine
Customer(age=55, isPregnant=false, name=Stasia) //fine
```

Comment: i see only one list printed....

Comment: when sorting twice, the 2nd sort will destroy the 1st result...

Comment: A comparator is always self-sufficient, why do you assume the comparator leaves te initial sorting intact?

Comment: Your comparators are both incorrect. The pregnant comparator shouldn't return 1 when bot are pregnant, but 0. The age comparator should return 0 when both are in the same age range. And of course, you need to combine the two comparison methods into just one: first compare by pregnancy, and then, if the result is 0, compare by age. The sort your list just once, with the combined comparator.

Comment: @Smutje can You provide me a tip on how I should write the comparator then? I tried but failed miserably. Although in the description of the exercise, it says that I should use both - Compartor and Comparable

Comment: Like others said, you can merge the two comparators into a single one. Another option is this: given that `Collections.sort()` is required to perform a stable sort, you can do lexicographic sorting with the two comparators. In this case however, you must first sort by the second and only then by the first.

Comment: Whenever you write a comparator, you need to make it reflective (`x == x`), commutative (if `x < y`, then `y > x`) and associative (if `x < y` and `y < z` then `x < z`) - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-.

Comment: Besides having implemented both, `compareTo` and `CustomerComparator` wrong, it is generally not a good idea to implement such a special constraint as *natural order* of a class as generic as `Customer`. Use a custom comparator for both and let the JRE take care of implementing it correctly: `pharmacyQueue.sort(Comparator.comparing(Customer::isPregnant).reversed().thenComparing(c -> c.getAge() < 60));`

Answer (score 2):

For that, you essentially need two things:

1. A [stable sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability), i.e. an algorithm that won't disturb order of "equal" (in terms of sort order) elements

   - You're lucky here, [`Collections.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) is guaranteed to be stable
2. A comparator that correctly identifies what elements are "equal"

   - That's where both your comparators fail - the age comparator doesn't even ever use info about the other object (!!!), and the pregnancy comparator has a bug that considers two pregnant customers to have a different priority.

Answer (score 0):

As pointing out in the comments, sorting the list twice does the same thing as sorting with the second ordering only (only slower). Oh, and many sorts such as QuickSort are unstable (rearrange tied values), whilst other such as MergeSort are stable.

You want to combine the comparators (or comparator and comparable). Fortunately (since 1.8) this is really easy with these two methods in `java.util.Comparator`

```
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<T> naturalOrder()

default Comparator<T> thenComparing​(Comparator<? super T> other)
```

Getting those the right way around is left as an exercise.

Comment: "sorting the list twice does the same thing as sorting with the second ordering only" is not true if the sort is *stable*.

Comment: @Holger With stable sort, if you first sort by first name and then sort again by surname, you get list sorted by "surname then first name" - which is different than sorting just by surname.

Comment: @JiriTousek I misread the statement itself. So in this form, it is only true when all property values of the sort criteria are distinct. Otherwise, it’s just false, whether the sort is stable or not.